# jQuery: uncheck/check checkboxes when those have checked attribute on page load

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitryfil/4pYaW/1/

- Browser - Chrome
- I have a series of checkboxes where one is checked by default.
- I have a select with a 2 options (where value of an option is linked to checkbox)
- When I try to check checkboxes, based on a select (so 2 should be selected), only 1 checkbox gets selected, and that's what I'm trying to figure out, why?

### HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item-a" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item-b" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item-c" />

<hr />

<select multiple>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

### JS:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);
//$('input[type=checkbox]:checked).removeAttr('checked');

$('select option').each(function(i, el){
    var val = $(this).attr('value');
    $('input[name=item-'+val+']').attr('checked', 'checked');
    //$('input[name=item-'+val+']').attr('checked', true);
});
```

### Notes:

- if checkbox is not checked by default, it works fine.
- when I unchecking with: attr('checked', false) and removeAttr('checked') - those produce different results.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change runtime properties of dom elements like `checked` and `selected`.

The value for these properties are boolean values like true/false instead of checked/selected.

```
$('input[name=item-'+val+']').prop('checked', true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TkREQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('select option').each(function(i, el){
    var val = $(this).prop('value');
    $('input[name=item-'+val+']').prop('checked', 'checked');
    //$('input[name=item-'+val+']').attr('checked', true);
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc7Xe/1/)</kbd>

A `prop()` is not same as `attr()` . `prop()` changes the property of an element where as `attr()` changes the attribute (the one written in html element )

I would highly advice you to go through all the answers here at
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)